# mysql query ordering by different column depending on value of another column

Tags: php, html, mysql, random, sequential

[image]

I have tried this code but it is not working.

```
$select=$conn->query("select * from tbl_testquestion ORDER BY SUBSTRING( type_id=0 qu_id RAND() ) , type_id=1 qu_id ASC");
```

please suggest edit if question not reached the standards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll want to use a case statement

```
SELECT *      
FROM tbl_testquestion 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN type_id=0 THEN RAND() 
        WHEN type_id=1 THEN qu_id 
    END ASC
```

Comment: yeah, upped - the title is a little hard to understand,  maybe change it to "mysql query: ordering by different column depending on value of another column"